# How to find the most close array in the 3-dimensions array

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

In my limited experience with `python & numpy`,  I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
A=[3,-1, 4]

B = array([1,1,1],[1,-1,1],[1,1,-1])

The most close one in B is [1, -1, 1]
```

1. the weight of positive and negative > close of (A, B)
2. find the most close one in B (all the same Pos or Neg)

`B1 = array([1,1,1], [1,-1,1], [1,1, -1], [3,1,4])`

`The result is [1,-1,1]`

after searching around for a decent XX solution and found that everything out there was difficult to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```
A = np.array([3,-1, 4])

B = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,-1,1],[1,1,-1]])

# distances array-wise
np.abs(B - A)

# sum of absolute values of distances (smallest is closest)
np.sum(np.abs(B - A), axis=1)

# index of smallest (in this case index 1)
np.argmin(np.sum(np.abs(B - A), axis=1))

# all in one line (take array 1 from B)
result = B[np.argmin(np.sum(np.abs(B - A), axis=1))]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, could you make some change that find the same +/- first, then cal the most close, I will be grateful to you

Comment: @Taufik_TF I don't really understand what you mean? `B == A` will give you an true/false array where matches are true. Use this like this `np.where(B==A)` which will give you the index of all exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([3,-1, 4])
B =np.array([[1,1,1],[1,-1,1],[1,1,-1]])
x=np.inf
for val  in B:
    if (x>(np.absolute(A-val)).sum())and((np.sign(A)==np.sign(val)).all()==True):   
        x=(np.absolute(A-val)).sum()
        y=val
print x
print y
```